# Im trying to plot multiple timeframes emas on same chart on trading view

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like emas from the hourly and 15 min chart but i can only get it to be either same as chart or one selected time frame

````
//{Variables declaration
var state = 0
//}
//{Indicators 
ema220 = ta.ema(close,220)
ema420 = ta.ema(close,420)
ema569 = ta.ema(close,569)
ma800 = ta.sma(close,800)
rsi = ta.rsi(close,14)
//}
// I WOULD LIKE ALL THE INDICATORS TO BE IN BOTH THE 1 HOURLY AND 15MIN


//{Alerts, Plots & colors
plot(ema220,color=color.green)
plot(ema420,color=color.red)
plot(ema569,color=color.black)
plot(ma800,color=color.yellow)
plot(rsi,color=color.red)
//alertcondition(longEntryCondition,"Enter Long")
//alertcondition(longExitCondition,"Exit Long")
//barcolor(state==1?color.lime:na)
//}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should use two `security` calls as described [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html).

One `security` for the 15min time frame and one for the 1h time frame.

Comment: Thanks im a bit of a noob to all this so will try and get my head around the securitys